# PHP Using str_replace along with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, filenames, image-file

I have a string of comma separated values that comes from a database, which actually are image paths. Like so:

`/images/us/US01021422717777-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422717780-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422717782-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422718486-m.jpg`

I then do like below, to split them at the `,` and convert them into paths for the web page.

`preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','<img class="gallery" src="$1">', $a)`

Works well, but in one place further in my page, I need to change the `-m` to `-l` (which means large)

When I do like below (put a str_replace inside the preg_replace), nothing happens. How can I do something like this?

`preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','<img class="gallery" src="$1" data-slide="'.str_replace('-m','-l','$1').'">', $a)`

Comment: Please inform volunteers if their answer are incorrect.  If one or more of the answers is correct, please award the green tick to the answer that you feel is "best" / "most helpful" / etc.  30% of all php question are currently deemed "unanswered" on Stackoverflow because they don't have a green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the `str_replace()` call in the output pattern for the `preg_replace()` call. That means `preg_replace()` is treating it as literal text.

What you want is something like this:

```
$imgtag = preg_replace(match, replacement, $a);
$imgtag = str_replace('-m','-l',$imgtag);
```

But, in my opinion it would be safer and easier to debug this stuff if you changed the order of your replacement operations, something like this:

```
foreach ($path in explode(",", $a)) {
  $path = str_replace('-m','-l',$path);
  $imgtag= sprintf ('<img class="gallery" src="%s">', $path);
  /* do something with the $imgtag */
}
```

That way you don't have to whistle into your modem :-)  to program that regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` on `preg_replace` return

```
$large = str_replace('-m','-l', preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','<img class="gallery" src="$1">', $a));
```

Output will be

```
<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717777-l.jpg">
<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717780-l.jpg">
<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717782-l.jpg">
<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422718486-l.jpg">
```

Comment: The `data-slide` needs to go with it. Like in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~',
    function (array $matches) {
        $src   = $matches[1];               // this is "$1"
        $slide = str_replace('-m', '-l', $matches[1]);
        return '<img class="gallery" src="'.$src.'" data-slide="'.$slide.'">';
    },
    $a
);
```

Instead of the replace expression, `preg_replace_callback()` gets as its second argument a function that receives the list of matched expressions and returns the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `str_replace` is simply invoked *before* `preg_replace` is invoked. Result of `str_replace` is then passed as argument to `preg_replace`.

What I could suggest is using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
function replace_img($match)
{
  return '<img class="gallery" src="' .
    $match[1] .
    '" data-slide="' .
    str_replace('-m','-l',$match[1]) .
    '">';
}

preg_replace_callback('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','replace_img', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need two separate outputs from each comma-separated value, I would write a pattern that stores the fullstring match and the substrings on either side of the `m` in each file.

*note: I match the trailing `-` in the first capture group and the leading `.` in the second capture group for minimal assurance of accuracy. This is somewhat weak validation; you can firm it up if your project requires it by adding literal or more restrictive pattern components in the capture groups.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/132e643b02853dcde653be4f51a56c7609c8f7fb))

```
$csv='/images/us/US01021422717777-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422717780-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422717782-m.jpg,/images/us/US01021422718486-m.jpg';
if(preg_match_all('~([^,]+-)m(\.[^,]+)~',$csv,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    foreach($out as $m){
        $mediums[]="<img class=\"gallery\" src=\"{$m[0]}\">";
        $larges[]="<img class=\"gallery\" src=\"{$m[0]}\" data-slide=\"{$m[1]}l{$m[2]}\">";
    }
}

var_export($mediums);
echo "\n\n";
var_export($larges);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717777-m.jpg">',
  1 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717780-m.jpg">',
  2 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717782-m.jpg">',
  3 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422718486-m.jpg">',
)

array (
  0 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717777-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717777-l.jpg">',
  1 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717780-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717780-l.jpg">',
  2 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422717782-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717782-l.jpg">',
  3 => '<img class="gallery" src="/images/us/US01021422718486-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422718486-l.jpg">',
)
```