# PHP preg_replace perform multiple replacements at different places

Tags: php, printf, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I get preg_replace to perform multiple replacements on the same string with different values at different places?

I actually have a comma separated string of image paths, that I split into multiple `<img src="">`tags like below.

`$a = /images/us/US01021422717777-%s.jpg,/images/us/US01021422717780-%s.jpg`

Then I do:

`preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','<img class="gallery" src="$1" data-slide="$1"></div>', $a)`

Which gives me:

`<img src="/images/us/US01021422717777-%s.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717777-%s.jpg">
<img src="/images/us/US01021422717780-%s.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717780-%s.jpg">`

What can I do to replace the first `%s` with `m` and the second `%s` with `%l`, using additional code in the same preg_replace statement itself. Without using preg_callback etc.

So my end results look like:

`<img src="/images/us/US01021422717777-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717777-l.jpg">
<img src="/images/us/US01021422717780-m.jpg" data-slide="/images/us/US01021422717780-l.jpg">`

I tried using `sprintf`, but it appears that will not work in this situation.

`sprintf(preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)\s?(?:,|$)~','<img class="gallery" src="$1" data-slide="$1"></div>', $a),'m','l')`

I'm sure you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. Any help on this?

Comment: You asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254349/php-using-str-replace-along-with-preg-replace) yesterday. I provided you [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254349/php-using-str-replace-along-with-preg-replace/28254473#28254473) for it. Isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try not to capture the `%s` part. Supposing it's always before the extension, you could do :

```
preg_replace('~\s?([^\s,]+)-%s(\.[a-z]+)\s?(?:,|$)~i','<img class="gallery" src="$1-m$2" data-slide="$1-l$2"></div>', $a)
```

Comment: Yes, the `%s` is always before the extension.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. Wont fail, will it?